# What is the meaning of the symbol H in the formula?

Tags: summation

It's a [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40jfq.png) I've got after finding sum. But I don't understand what H means

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [generalized harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers).